# Selecting Item From Category id

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to select items for my different category table but its shows only the i use with If() and I'm trying to use elseif

```
if($get_idy='Cars'){    
            $sel = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM item WHERE category='Cars' ");
            }elseif($get_idy='Trucks'){
                            $sel = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM item WHERE category='Trucks' ");
                             }
            while($row= mysqli_fetch_array($sel))
            {
```

Can someone help?

Comment: `IF` condition is : `if($get_idy=='Cars') `. write like this.Refer this http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php for more help.

Comment: It is always assigning 'Cars' to the variable $get_idy in your if condition as mentioned by @Nidhi. So, if condition is always true & that is where your error is.

Comment: Please is not still working, its selecting only the cars but i want to know where how i can select all differently

Comment: Thanks i just get what you are trying to say, it works

Answer (score 0):

You have put wrong if condition in your code.Single "=" assign the value in variable and double "==" check variable value is same or not. It should be like below.

```
    if($get_idy=='Cars'){    
                         $sel = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM item WHERE category='Cars' ");
                    } elseif($get_idy=='Trucks'){
                         $sel = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM item WHERE category='Trucks' ");
                    } else{
                       echo "The category is empty";
                    }
                    while($row= mysqli_fetch_array($sel))
                    {
                    }
```

Comment: But please how can i assign the, if there is nothing in the category echo "The category is empty

Comment: @Marc ok i will add this in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could have done like this instead checking condition for every category,

```
$sel = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM item WHERE category='".$get_idy."'");
while($row= mysqli_fetch_array($sel)) {
   //Your code here.
}
```

Please start using PDO as your sql is vulnerable to SQL Injections

Update: posted this update based on your comment

```
if(isset($get_idy)) {
  $sel = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM item WHERE category='".$get_idy."'");
  while($row= mysqli_fetch_array($sel)) {
     //Your code here.
 }
} else {
   echo "The category is empty";
}
```

Comment: Wow, its very cool like that, thanks a lot i really appreciate each and every one of you

Comment: But please how can i assign the, if there is nothing in the category echo "The category is empty

Comment: @Marc, just posted an update to the answer if there is nothing in the category